# Python: return в методах

Tags: python, ооп, return

В чем разница между методом класса, который содержит return, и в котором return не содержится?
Например:

```
class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self, name, level):
        ...
        self.level = level

    def levelUp(self, level_plus):
        self.level = self.level + level_plus
        return self.level

    def info(self):
        print("Name is: ", self.name)
        print("Level is: ", self.level)

rSomeClass = SomeClass("Red", 34)
rSomeClass.levelUp(14)
rSomeClass.info()
```

и

```
class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self, name, level):
        ...
        self.level = level

    def levelUp(self, level_plus):
        self.level = self.level + level_plus

    def info(self):
        print("Name is: ", self.name)
        print("Level is: ", self.level)

rSomeClass = SomeClass("Green", 16)
rSomeClass.levelUp(32)
rSomeClass.info()
```

В обоих примерах кода переменная экземпляра изменила свое значение. Но есть ли неочевидные отличия между ними?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отличие в том, что в одном случае в результате выполнения функции возвращается значение, которое можно использовать в коде. В случае, когда функция не содержит `return` - она возвращает `None` по умолчанию.

У вас функция levelUp может быть использована так:

```
print('Поздравляем с получением уровня', rSomeClass.levelUp(32))  # такое невозможно без использования return
```

В одну строку и уровень увеличили, и текущий уровень смогли отобразить.

Грамотное использование`return` позволяет банально уменьшить количество кода.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно, так и получается.

Answer (score 1):

Return есть у любой функции. Просто если он явно не задан, то возвращается None. А так вы можете возвращать нужные вам значения. Других отличий нет.